# MergeMap into Map RxJS Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am currently learning RxJS and dont get it. I have this code:

```
mapOfPeople = new Map<number, any>();

const people = [
  { name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }
];

from(people)
  .pipe(
    groupBy(
      person => person.age,
      p => p
    ),
    mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

This code is from a tutorial.

I want to put the output into the given hashmap. How do I manage this? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get your initial code to compile, and I'm not sure what the zip part is for in this context.

One way of doing it is to use the subscribe function handler. At the moment it is console.log - but you can do anything here of the format `(arg) => void` (a function which takes an item from the observable and handles it in some way.

Here's an example which adds the array of people of each age into the map:

```
type Person = { name: string, age: number};

const mapOfPeople = new Map<number, Person[]>();

const people = [
  { name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }
];

from(people).pipe(
  groupBy(person => person.age),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
).subscribe(people => {
  // the age of any in this group of people is the key
  const { age } = people[0];

  // set as map's value for this age
  mapOfPeople.set(age, people);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to just add a reduce operator at the end in this fairly contrived example:

```
from(people)
  .pipe(
    groupBy(
      person => person.age,
      p => p
    ),
    mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray()))),
    reduce((acc, v) => {
      acc.set(v[0], v[1])
      return acc
    }, new Map<number, any>())
  )
  .subscribe(m => mapOfPeople = m);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapOfPeople: any;

const people = [
  { name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }
];

from(people)
  .pipe(
    groupBy(
      person => person.age,
      p => p
    ),
    mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
  )
  .subscribe(res => mapOfPeople = res /*or do whatever you want with the result*/);
```

For more info: [observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)